# Why Netlify Run Time Error shows while deploying?

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, netlify, nodemon

> "scripts": {
> "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
> "start": "nodemon index.js"
> }
> netlify shows
> 9:32:09 PM: build-image version: 01daab3416c9da7032f1dcdb8b1adffdaf5ccb74 (focal)
> 9:32:09 PM: buildbot version: 01daab3416c9da7032f1dcdb8b1adffdaf5ccb74
> 9:32:09 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
> 9:32:09 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
> 9:32:09 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
> 9:32:10 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
> 9:32:10 PM: git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/abak02/medicine-shop
> 9:32:10 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
> 9:32:11 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
> 9:32:12 PM: Starting build script
> 9:32:12 PM: Installing dependencies
> 9:32:12 PM: Python version set to 2.7
> 9:32:13 PM: v16.19.0 is already installed.
> 9:32:13 PM: Now using node v16.19.0 (npm v8.19.3)
> 9:32:13 PM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
> 9:32:13 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
> 9:32:13 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
> 9:32:13 PM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
> 9:32:14 PM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
> 9:32:14 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
> 9:32:14 PM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
> 9:32:14 PM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
> 9:32:14 PM: No npm workspaces detected
> 9:32:14 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
> 9:32:14 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
> 9:32:15 PM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.19.3
> 9:32:17 PM: added 200 packages, and audited 201 packages in 2s
> 9:32:17 PM: 18 packages are looking for funding
> 9:32:17 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
> 9:32:17 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
> 9:32:17 PM: npm packages installed
> 9:32:17 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
> 9:32:17 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
> 9:32:17 PM: go version go1.19.5 linux/amd64
> 9:32:17 PM: Detected 0 framework(s)
> 9:32:17 PM: Installing missing commands
> 9:32:17 PM: Verify run directory
> 9:32:17 PM: Section completed: initializing
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM:   Netlify Build
> 9:32:19 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM: ❯ Version
> 9:32:19 PM:   @netlify/build 29.5.4
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM: ❯ Flags
> 9:32:19 PM:   baseRelDir: true
> 9:32:19 PM:   buildId: 63ea57f258aa1f2e036784c2
> 9:32:19 PM:   deployId: 63ea57f258aa1f2e036784c4
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM: ❯ Current directory
> 9:32:19 PM:   /opt/build/repo
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM: ❯ Config file
> 9:32:19 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM: ❯ Context
> 9:32:19 PM:   production
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app
> 9:32:19 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 9:32:19 PM: ​
> 9:32:19 PM: $ npm start
> 9:32:19 PM: > drug-website@1.0.0 start
> 9:32:19 PM: > nodemon index.js
> 9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] 2.0.20
> 9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
> 9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
> 9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
> 9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> 10:18:05 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime

Deploy a nodejs project but runtime error

Answer (score 0):

```
9:32:19 PM: $ npm start
9:32:19 PM: drug-website@1.0.0 start
9:32:19 PM: nodemon index.js
9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] 2.0.20
9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] watching path(s): .
9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
9:32:19 PM: [nodemon] starting node index.js
10:18:05 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime
```

The problem is in that part. Netlify is meant to run static apps. Your build process should run some commands and "exit" the process with some output. You can't run a server in the build process that waits for eternity.